# TokenMismatchException in production

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I just got my laravel app running on the server. But I got an error in registration process. It says something like:

```
[2015-05-27 12:38:34] production.ERROR: exception 'Illuminate\Session\TokenMismatchException' in /var/www/vendor/compiled.php:2545
```

Please help. The code works fine on local environment but not on production.

**EDIT**:

```
            <div class="panel panel-default">
            <div class="panel-heading">Register</div>
            <div class="panel-body">
                @if (count($errors) > 0)
                    <div class="alert alert-danger">
                        <strong>Whoops!</strong> There were some problems with your input.<br><br>
                        <ul>
                            @foreach ($errors->all() as $error)
                                <li>{{ $error }}</li>
                            @endforeach
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                @endif

                <form class="form-horizontal" role="form" method="POST" action="{{ url('/auth/register') }}">
                    <input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Name</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="text" class="form-control" name="name" value="{{ old('name') }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">E-Mail Address</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" value="{{ old('email') }}">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="col-md-4 control-label">Confirm Password</label>
                        <div class="col-md-6">
                            <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password_confirmation">
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="form-group">
                        <div class="col-md-6 col-md-offset-4">
                            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" name="submit">
                                Register
                            </button>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
```

And here is the part of my postRegister which is as is provided.

```
public function postRegister(Request $request)
{
    $validator = $this->registrar->validator($request->all());

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }

    $this->auth->login($this->registrar->create($request->all()));

    return redirect($this->redirectPath());
}
```

And my controller i.e. AuthController is as provided. As well as routes are not even touched. It works on Local but not on Production.

Comment: Try to go back to the registration page pres f5 and if it happens again tell me

Comment: Tried it several times. Tested code back on the development but still same error.

Comment: Alright, do you have a hidden token in the form?

Comment: hmm could you post some of the code of the view, route and the controller?

Comment: The code looks fine and probably is as it works on localhost. maybe a stupid question but did you do composer install?

Comment: @Szenis here is the code

Comment: That's the first step I always do @Szenis

Comment: Does `_token` update regularly or is it static for a session. Because mine is updating very regularly at every refresh.

Comment: I just checked my own website and if i do a page refresh the token stays the same

Comment: Can you do a Log::info($request->input('_token')); in your production env ?
And tell us what is logged. If something is logged, that means an ajax request might be performed when your DOM is ready, and it changes your session csrf_token. If not, you don't correctly send the _token value to your controller

Comment: @ChainList Hmm. But my controller is as provided from fresh laravel install.

Answer (score 0):

Production is not catching an error because of the secure configuration in *config/session.php.*

By default, it is set up as "false" and if you have an SSL working on the hosting server, change a value of 'secure' from **"false"** to **"true"** in the session.php file, on the remote server.

Session.php file

```
'secure' => true //false
```

Note: I have not tested.

Source: https://laracasts.com/discuss/channels/laravel/tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftokenphp-line-67-in-laravel-52?page=2

Answer (score -2):

Please try adding this in your form --

```
<input type="hidden" name="_token" value="{{ csrf_token() }}">
```

For more detail visit -- http://laravel.io/forum/01-30-2015-laravel5-tokenmismatchexception-in-verifycsrftoken